# Adding gesture to label

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to add tap gesture to a label. But it is not working:

**My code:**

```
@IBOutlet var nameLabel: UILabel!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    var nameTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "nameTapped")
    nameTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    nameTap.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1
    nameLabel.addGestureRecognizer(nameTap)
}
```

I tried the same code for an image view, it works perfectly. Why this is not working for label ?

Comment: Maybe adding `nameLabel.userInteractionEnabled = YES`?

Comment: @Larme Yes, it worked :) Please add this comment as a answer, i will mark it.